# Which special editions of the PS4 feature the updated power supply?

Tags: ps4, hardware

I have heard the PS4 has recently been updated. I like some of the changes, including the mechanical power and eject buttons, but I especially like the improved power supply. I read some articles about the updates, but I have yet to read a list of which special editions feature the upgrades. Which special editions of the PS4 feature the updated power supply and other upgrades?

Comment: IDK, but If I had to guess I'd say all the models that are 1TB and not 500GB.

Comment: That I could understand. Personally, I am more specifically interested in the Batman and Taken King editions of the PS4 (both which are 500GB), but I thought that I would ask for a more comprehensive list since I haven't found one yet.

Comment: Should you not be able to tell from pictures of them if they have different power and eject buttons?

Comment: @BryanF well just look at release dates on amazon. Look at when the updated ps4s started coming out, then look at the release date and the bundles you are intrested in.

Comment: @BryanF aha! I think I got this: http://www.amazon.com/PlayStation-500GB-Console-Black-Bundle-4/dp/B018V3ISJ2/ref=sr_1_1?s=videogames&ie=UTF8&qid=1455248220&sr=1-1&keywords=PS4 
Scroll down near the bottom. There is hardware specs.

Comment: @AshwinGupta When the new models were released there were also still new consoles with the older version released as well. I remember the first 1 TB version being the CUH 1100 while there was already a CUH 1200 500GB version available. The Batman bundle came out around the time of the new version but seems to be the old version still. The version is also often not shown in online item descriptions, like in your link. The general hardware specs didn't change with new versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new version of the PS4 is called "CUH-1200". There are different numbers for this version, depending on the territory, e.g. the European relese is called "CUH-1216", the US release "CUH 1215".

There is also a letter after this number, signifying the HDD space. The 500 GB version is called "CUH-1216A" and the 1 TB version "CUH-1216B". I'm not sure about the exact release date, but the 1200 models have been released somewhere around July/August 2015, so any console from before that time will be one of the older models.

Make sure to look up the number before purchasing the console. It should state it somewhere on the package, otherwise you should ask the seller before purchasing. It is also a good idea to search amazon reviews for clarification which number the console has, if it isn't stated in the description.

In some countries, online stores will show the version number on the article page, like [amazon.de](http://amazon.de/PlayStation-Konsole-500GB-schwarz-CUH-1216A/dp/B010TNVS1W/).

Regarding the console bundles you're interested in, according to their amazon reviews and [a post on the US Playstation blog](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2015/07/30/limited-edition-destiny-the-taken-king-ps4-bundle-pre-orders-open-today/#comment-1102345), the [US Taken King bundle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B012UGC9F0) is the new 1200 model.

The [Batman Limited Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VETEZ34), however, seems to be the older 1100 model, according to [this post from a Playstation community manager](https://medium.com/@PadPoet/further-differences-between-cuh-1100-and-cuh-1200-387c3241bd31#.moqgxuxrh).

In case you're interested, [here](http://zrzhub.com/ps/comparing-ps4-skus-cuh-1000-cuh-1100-and-cuh-1200/) is a good comparison between the three models.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response! The model numbers are exactly what I was trying to articulate.